# How to exit Python Azure Function in secure way?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I'am looking for the best way of escaping from Azure Function Flow written in Python.

I was using something like:

```py
try:
    some_operations()
except ErrorName as err:
    print(err)
    exit(0)
```

Unfortunately I found that function calls which should finished in this way, are getting long timeouts. All needed actions are performed correctly but final response code of the function is 500

I'm wondering if there will be difference if i will use

```py
sys.exit(0)
```

Please let me know if you know some better approach, or got some nice reading regarding this problem.

To be specific, I use:
python 3.7
and event grid triggered function

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use `raise Exception(err)` instead of `print(err)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out that the best solution which is not freezing the entire function is to use a return statement.

```py
try:
    some_operations()
except ErrorName as err:
    print(err)
    return 0
```

or

```py
try:
    some_operations()
except ErrorName as err:
    return 'something which gives any kind of info'
```

I have changed it in my case, and many stuck events from EventGridSubscription just came successfully.

Comment: This is a good solution, But and there is a big But... in case you use this try-catch inside for each statment the whole script isn't terminated. Just the for each part.. in case you want to exit the script, use `raise Exception`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's strange that sys.exit() will freeze the function execution.